# How to properly show quotes in HTML input text

Tags: javascript, escaping

I need to show a string like `value='dummy'` inside an input `type=text`. Which is the correct way to do it?

If i use `&lt;input type=text value='+escape(str)+"'&gt;`  I get `value%3D%27dummy%27`. If I don't escape I do not see anything after the first quote. I would like to see the string in the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use unescape in this case, try

```
'<input type="text" value="'+unescape(str)+'">'
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't use string to define the value. Instead, select the DOM element, and set its value.

```
// Provided you select your input in the "input" variable
input.value = str
```

This way, you don't have to bother with escaping/unescaping.

Answer (score 1):

If your value is surrounded by single quotes then:

```
"<input type='text' value='"+"John's".replace(/'/igm,"&apos;")+"' />";
```

If your value is surrounded by double quotes then:

```
'<input type="text" value="'+'"one two"'.replace(/"/igm,"&quot;")+'" />';
```

If you're not sure:

```
'<input type="text" value="'+'"one two Jon\'s"'.replace(/"/igm,"&quot;").
   replace(/'/igm,"&apos;")+'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type='text' value="value='dummy'">   </input>
```

edit : sorry I realized this is not what you want, see **gillesc** answer